# Error from DNS validation service: RFC821 4.3

Tags: domain-name-system, email

So I've managed to setup bind9 and a mail server, but it seems there is something wrong.
I don't quite under stand this error:

```
The configuration of your mail servers and your DNS are not ok! The report of the test is: 
mail.aplision.com. -> mail.aplision.com -> 208.xxx.xxx.xxx -> lisa.aplision.com
Spam recognition software and RFC821 4.3 (also RFC2821 4.3.1) state that the hostname given in the SMTP greeting MUST have an A record pointing back to the same server.
```

Can anyone explain this to me in a bit more detail, and maybe point me in a direction to solve this?

Comment: please quote the real domain name.

Comment: edited original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is complaining because the IP address of your mail server has a PTR record which refers to a hostname (`lisa.aplision.com`) which does not itself exist.

Simply add:

```
lisa IN A 208.77.101.5
```

to your zone file and all should be well.